# Replace inequality to equation

Tags: replacement, inequalities

I have a region of inequalities from a `RegionPlot[]`:

```
r = {3 x + 2 y > 24 && x + y < 12 && y < 1/2 x && y > 1}
```

I want to change it a `ContourPlot[]` Input, i.e., to replace the Greater/Less Than Signs to Equal Signs and `&&` to `,` that will look like this:

```
{3 x + 2 y == 24, x + y == 12, y == 1/2 x, y == 1}
```

Thanks for your kind notice and help!

Comment: How about `{3 x + 2 y > 24 && x + y < 12 && y < 1/2 x && y > 1} /. {Greater -> 
   Equal, Less -> Equal}`

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use `Apply[]` to make the replacements:

```
Equal @@@ List @@ (3 x + 2 y > 24 && x + y < 12 && y < 1/2 x && y > 1)
   {3 x + 2 y == 24, x + y == 12, y == x/2, y == 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to apply a rule that replaces the symbols > and < by the equality ==, and the And by a List. r2 is your desired result

> r = {3 x + 2 y > 24 && x + y < 12 && y < 1/2 x && y > 1}
>
> r2 = (r /. {Greater -> Equal, Less -> Equal, And -> List})[[1]]

Answer (score 0):

You can also temporarily re-define `Less` and  `Greater` as `Equal` and `And` as `Sequence` using [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html):

```
Block[{Less = Equal, Greater = Equal, And = Sequence}, r]
```

> ```
> {3 x + 2 y == 24, x + y == 12, y == x/2, y == 1}
> ```